# Why did Case Type get stripped from all Smart Groups after upgrade to 4.6.9?

Tags: civicase, upgrade, smartgroups

Drupal 7.41

After upgrade to CiviCRM 4.6.9, all Smart Groups that had a case type in the criteria were empty.

When I looked at the criteria for each group, the case type was stripped from the search.

I manually added each one back in and ran a rebuild and everything appears to be ok now.

Any idea what may have caused this?

Comment: We're experiencing the same thing-- but in our situation, the case type reference has *changed*, not been dropped out.  We can tell when we "edit smart group criteria" that the criteria is not what it was prior to upgrade.  Is this the same or different from https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17313 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer necessary for this question.

More recent versions of Civi seem to have resolved this issue.